# Replacing an AC drive in my mill and the use of a magnetic contactor in the power supply line

Tags: ac, three-phase, magnetics, drive

I have a small mill in my shop that I converted from single phase 110V 1hp motor to a 220V 3phase 2hp motor using a Teco Jnev 202. When I did that about 10 years ago I just wired it off a 30 A breaker and used a control box that had an on/off, fwd/rev and a shutoff switch. That drive failed last month and I bought a Fuji FRN0010C2S-7U to replace it.

When I install this new drive I am adding a braking resistor and I also want to ensure I wire it in correctly. I am trying to decide if I need to use a magnetic contactor along with a molded case circuit breaker in place of just using a 30 A breaker to supply power. I am coming into the drive with 220V single phase. I've read that in some cases a mag contactor is not needed, so I am looking for recommendations that explain what the best way to correctly wire this drive's power supply.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. “Benefits of” is boarderline an open ended question and SE is a more strict question-answer site. Can you narrow it down to an answerable question?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use a motor protection device, or circuit breaker. Averything should be described in the operating manual, incudilng size, wire cross section,...

You would need a contactor if you need an emergency stop. It's up to you to decide.

[image]

You see, that 20 A is suitable for your inverter, not 30A.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking and based on what I've read that a amag contactor would be needed based on the load on the power supply.